# brit-milah for dead infant

Tags: halacha, death, brit-milah, funeral-burial-levaya, current-events

Recent tragedy in NY, young haredi couple killed in auto accident.
Wife pregnant with baby boy.
Doctors delivered the baby but, tragically, he also didn't survive.
Before burial, a brit milah was performed on the dead infant.
What, if any, is the halachic basis for this?

Comment: Dup: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/26872/why-is-a-bris-performed-after-death (but note that that one doesn't have any answers as of right now).