# Do we circumcise a corpse?

Tags: death, brit-milah

We circumcise stillborn babies for many reasons (see e.g., [here](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/2432015/jewish/Post-mortem-Naming-and-Circumcision-for-a-Stillbirth.htm)). Would the same apply for one who it was unhealthy for him to receive a brit milah?

For example, let's say person A's two brothers both died receiving a brit milah. We assume that he too will die from the brit milah and do not give him a brit milah. When he dies, should we give him a brit milah just like we would give the stillborn a brit milah?

Comment: Related: "[Why is a bris performed after death](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/26872/1368)"?

Comment: No, this would not be *kavod ha'mes*.

Comment: @TheGRAPKE burial societies in Israel appear to see it differently: https://www.jta.org/1993/08/17/archive/post-mortem-circumcisions-opposed - if you dig into the issue you see that some believe that being uncircumcised is shameful, see e.g., [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/26882/11501)

Comment: survey of relevant classical sources by someone affiliated with the Conservative movement: https://www.rabbinicalassembly.org/sites/default/files/public/halakhah/teshuvot/2011-2020/post-mortem-circumcision.pdf

Comment: @mbloch *Halachah* versus sensitivity (which makes you wonder if that was the *halachah* in the first place).

Comment: @TheGRAPKE absolutely, and if you read the survey of sources, you will see it is not at all black and white that one should circumcise. The SA seems to have innovated in making a clear ruling

Comment: @TheGRAPKE If you look at the link I included in the question, it shows many reasons why it is very respectful to the dead. We are letting them enter Gan Eden, blocking them from gehenom, saving them from embarrassment, and many other ways.

Comment: @YosefZaghi These are kabbalistic notions, but do not override the halachical *darkei noam* principle (https://outorah.org/p/38311/).

Comment: According to him, yes: http://www.mohelinsouthflorida.com/2015/12/being-uncircumcised-jew.html